# How can I use a uTLS connection when sending a request?

Tags: http, go, request, tls1.2

I'm trying to send a request using a Hello Chrome fingerprint by using the uTLS library, but after looking through the docs I'm struggling to figure out how to utilise the uTLS connection when sending a request.

I've got both parts of the code below, but not sure how to put them together, or if I'm even doing it the correct way.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"

    tls "github.com/refraction-networking/utls"
)

func main() {

    tcpConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "151.101.65.69:443")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("net.Dial() failed: %+v\n", err)
        return
    }
    config := tls.Config{ServerName: "www.stackoverflow.com"}
    tlsConn := tls.UClient(tcpConn, &config, tls.HelloChrome_Auto)
    defer tlsConn.Close()

    err = tlsConn.Handshake()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("uTlsConn.Handshake() error: %+v", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Handshake met")
    }

    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

    client := &http.Client{
        Jar:       cookieJar,
        Transport: &http.Transport{},
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://ja3er.com/json", nil)
    req.Header.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply move your code into [Transport.DialTLSContext](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.DialTLSContext):

> DialTLSContext specifies an optional dial function for creating
> TLS connections for non-proxied HTTPS requests.
>
> [...]
>
> The returned net.Conn is assumed to already be
> past the TLS handshake.

```
client := &http.Client{
    Jar: cookieJar,
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialTLSContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            // Note that hardcoding the address is not necessary here. Only
            // do that if you want to ignore the DNS lookup that already
            // happened behind the scenes.

            tcpConn, err := (&net.Dialer{}).DialContext(ctx, network, addr) 
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            config := tls.Config{ServerName: "www.stackoverflow.com"}
            tlsConn := tls.UClient(tcpConn, &config, tls.HelloChrome_Auto)

            err = tlsConn.Handshake()
            if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("uTlsConn.Handshake() error: %w", err)
            }

            return tlsConn, nil
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I seem to get a constant error of```tcp [addr]->[addr] use of closed network connection```

Comment: I overlooked the deferred Close call. That's not supposed to be there, of course. I updated the answer.

Comment: That works flawlessly on some sites, yet some I get ```net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x12\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x04\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\u007f\xff\x00\x00\x00\x0
0\b\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01"```

Comment: That’s due to not handling the HTTP1 request. The sites you are having issues with don’t support http2.